# how to genrate notifaction when configMap change

Tags: kubernetes, environment-variables, devops, amazon-eks, configmap

I have node base application and I have many configmap so when someone changes into my configmap that time I need  notification, for notification I am using kubewatch but when some edit configmap notification not coming